# How to declare functions after event listener occcurs

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I've been trying to make this Music Playing script with the Audio element.
So what my problem is that I don't want these functions to be available before the Metadata is loaded.

I'm using this object here.

```
var MusicPlayer = new Object();
MusicPlayer.source;
MusicPlayer.duration = 0;
MusicPlayer.Player =  new Audio();
MusicPlayer.metadataloaded = false;
```

What I attempted was to firstly, create a function which defines these functions and this function itself is loaded by the event listener.

```
function Playerinitialize()
{
MusicPlayer.metadataloaded = true;
}
```

Then

```
MusicPlayer.Player.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function()
{

MusicPlayer.duration = this.duration;
console.log(this.duration);
console.log(MusicPlayer.duration / 60);
console.log(this.currentTime);
Playerinitialize();

});
```

But it doesn't work saying currentTime is undefined. So how do i achieve this moreover, I'm doing this to prevent this functions being called while Audio objects duration is NaN etc. Is this the most efficient way? 
And why can't i use Prototype to add functions to MusicPlayer Object?

Comment: @Rajesh i don't quite get you, I understand the basics of callback but i couldn't really make out what you meant(new here :>).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, take look at this. You will find  all eventhandlers and more about Audio object you need here: [Audio](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp)

I think Something like this should suit you (Edited):

```
function  MusicPlayer(src, ready){
    var player =  new Audio();

    var controller = { };

    controller.play = function(){
        player.play();
    };

    //add to controller all parameters you need here

    player.onloadedmetadata = function() {
        //do your things here: after metadata is loaded

        //add to controller some more parameters 
        //retrieve your object:

        ready(controller);

    };

    player.src = src;   
}

var ready = function(controller){
    //do with your player what you think is necessary
    //via controller like:
    controller.play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @blindProgrammer